# What happen next if Android VersionCode reach 2100000000?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

The title is clear enough.

[The site](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning) says that's the limit

> Warning: The greatest value Google Play allows for versionCode is 2100000000.

I just curious, what happens if the Android VersionCode reach 2100000000?

What if you accidentally type 2100000000 in your version code and publish it. What can you do for the next update?

I can't sleep thinking about it. I don't need sleep, I need an answer

Thank you. Cheers

Comment: Interesting question, but I think nobody will have this problem unless you intentionally do so.

Comment: The paragraphs directly above the warning seems to cover what will happen: you can still publish new versions with a lower versioncode as long as you haven't used those exact versioncodes before, but users can only upgrade to a version that has a higher versioncode than the version they already have installed.

Comment: 2B releases are not enough for you? If you think about it then this many releases will last forever.

Comment: @RudrikPatel, I understand 2B will be more than enough even though you upload every second it will last for a lifetime. But I just curious what if you accidentally use the last version code. What can you do next?

Comment: @SusiS True. But, in that case as far as the documentation is a concern we don't have the actual scenario given to us developers. I guess try dropping a mail on Google Support?

Comment: @RudrikPatel I hope someone has done that so, they can share what they do. If no one has experienced this, I think I'll drop an email to Google Support. Cause I really can't sleep

Comment: LOL, I will upvote this question so you can finally go to sleep after an answer is given

Comment: maybe just publish some dummy app with initial version code `2099999999`, then put some update with `2100000000`, maybe there will be some prompt related to this max value? after that try to update to `2100000001`, then you will find out what Console say

Comment: Is there any answer about this?